# Given an emacs command name, how would you find key-bindings ? (and vice versa)

Tags: emacs

If I know an emacs command name, says, "goto-line"; what if I want to query whether if there are any key-sequences bound to this command ?

And vice versa, given a key sequence, how can I find its command name ?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

To just find key bindings for a command, you can use emacs help's "where-is" feature

```
C-h w command-name
```

If multiple bindings are set for the command they will all be listed.

For the inverse, given a key sequence, you can type

```
C-h k key-sequence
```

To get the command that would run.

You can get detailed information about a command, also any non-interactive function defined, by typing

```
C-h f function-name
```

Which will give you detailed information about a function, including any key bindings for it, and

```
C-h v variable-name
```

will give you information about any (bound) variable. Key-maps are kept in variables, however the key codes are stored in a raw format.  Try `C-h v isearch-mode-map` for an example.

For more help on getting help, you can type

```
C-h ?
```

Comment: You can also do `C-h w <function name>` to know just where the key is, not the full documentation. Conversely, you can also do `C-h c <key sequence>` to just know what function is bound to a key sequence.

Comment: also:  C-h w is typically bound to where-is.

Comment: So, I can where-is where-is when I forget C-h w. That's great ! ;)

Comment: It would be good if one could generate a list of all current key bindings...must be possible.

Comment: @ftravers - the `which-key` package on MELPA (also part of the Spacemacs config.) does a fine job of this.  It shows the available key bindings after an initial prefix is entered. (e.g. `C-x`)  a list of top level bindings can be shown using `M-x which-key-show-top-level`

Comment: minor typo correction: s/`C-h f variable-name`/`C-h v variable-name`

Comment: For those who have bound `C-h` to something else in their window managers:
`C-h w` is equivalent to `M-x where-is`.
`C-h k` is equivalent to `M-x describe-key`.
`C-h f` is equivalent to `M-x describe-function`.
`C-h v` is equivalent to `M-x describe-variable`.
`C-h ?` is equivalent to `M-x help-for-help`.
Also note that `f1` can be used instead of `C-h`.

Answer (score 17):

For interactively getting the command bound to a keyboard shortcut (or a key sequence in Emacs terms), see the selected answer.

For programmatically getting the command bound to a given key sequence, use the function `key-binding` or `lookup-key` that takes a key sequence and returns its bound command. The function `key-binding` is what `C-h k` uses.

```
(key-binding (kbd "C-h m"))
```

returns the command bound to `C-h m` by searching in all current keymaps. The function `lookup-key` searches in a single keymap:

```
(lookup-key (current-global-map) (kbd "TAB")) ; => indent-for-tab-command
(lookup-key org-mode-map (kbd "TAB")) ; => org-cycle
(lookup-key text-mode-map (kbd "TAB")) ; => nil
(lookup-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "TAB")) ; => isearch-printing-char
```

For programmatically getting all key sequences bound to a given command, `where-is-internal` is probably the function to use. The name of the function ending with `internal` seems to suggest that it's not for Emacs users to use in their init files but this function having a docstring seems to suggest otherwise. Anyone considering use of `where-is-internal` should first check if [remapping keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html#Remapping-Commands) instead can achieve their goal.

An alternative for finding the keys that are bound to a specific command (e.g., `forward-char`) is `substitute-command-keys` (e.g., `(substitute-command-keys "\\[forward-char]")`).
That is especially useful in larger texts.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `where-is-internal` suggests it’s OK to use it. Also, conventionally we use a format like `where-is--internal` (note the double dash) for “private” functions.

Comment: Usage of suffix `-internal` is described there: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Names.html#Function-Names. It should be used for internal C functions.

Answer (score 13):

`C-h w` (or `F1-w`): `where-is` RET somecommandname RET

Does just what you're asking - lists bound keys with no additional information. :)

Answer (score 6):

An old question, but for the benefit of new readers, there are some other nice ways to see key bindings

#### `M-x describe-bindings`

Lists all the bindings currently available, use isearch, occur, etc. to make good use of this list.

#### `M-x describe-prefix-map`

This shows all the bindings available from the current mode, you can use the display buffer as you would any other readonly Emacs buffer, for example you can search freely for strings etc.

#### `M-x describe-mode`

As well as giving you general info about the current mode, it will also list all the key bindings available.

#### `M-x describe-minor-mode`

You will be prompted to enter the name of a minor mode, and then be shown info and key bindings for that minor mode.

**NOTE** : The examples below use additional packages (available from [MELPA](http://melpa.org))

#### Which key

This shows you bindings just before you need them.  Enter a prefix, for example `C-x` or `C-c` and a list of the bindings available in that prefix will be shown.

You can also view a list of key bindings available from the current mode by using:

#### `M-x which-key-show-top-level`

It is useful to bind `which-key-show-top-level` to a key chord of your choice, so you can view the keys available from anywhere.

For example, `C-s` (`isearch-forward`) has an extensive key map which often unknown.  e.g. `M-s o` starts `occur` using the current search string, I didn't know about this for many many years of using Emacs.  Having `which-key` around has helped me discover many rare gems in Emacs.

https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key

#### Guide key

Guide key works in much the same way as `which-key` I'd recommend taking a look at it to compare features.

https://github.com/kai2nenobu/guide-key

Answer (score 0):

The `lookup-key` function works well, but there's no function for finding the key binding programmatically from a command AFAIK. The following does that and is based on the `slime-cheat-sheet` command.

```lisp
(defun lookup-function (keymap func)
  (let ((all-bindings (where-is-internal (if (symbolp func)
                                             func
                                           (cl-first func))
                                         keymap))
        keys key-bindings)
    (dolist (binding all-bindings)
      (when (and (vectorp binding)
                 (integerp (aref binding 0)))
        (push binding key-bindings)))
    (push (mapconcat #'key-description key-bindings " or ") keys)
    (car keys)))

(lookup-key (current-global-map) (kbd "C-x C-b"))    ; => list-buffers
(lookup-function (current-global-map) 'list-buffers) ; => "C-x C-b"
```

Interactively, as @ShreevatsaR suggested, you can use `C-h w <function name>` (`where-is`) and `C-h c <key sequence>` (`describe-key-briefly`). See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Help.html) for more information.