# For Emacs, how to bind keys only in certain action?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Specifically, I'd like to change the key bindings of Emacs-Helm.  When I run `helm-find-files`, if I hit `C-z` on a directory, you can jump into the selected directory.  I'd like to change this behavior to `Tab`.  I know the action bound to `C-z` is `helm-execute-persistanet-action`.  I can achieve this by doing `(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistanet-action)` but then that will capture all other `tab` actions.  I only want `tab` to run `helm-execute-persistanet-action` when I'm in `helm-find-files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is define-key. The expression should look like:
(define-key helm-mode-map [tab] 'a-command)

Comment: so the answer was: (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to advice around the helm-find-files function to declare a variable in-helm-find-files then bind the tab key in the helm keymap  using define-key. If the in-helm-find is set then you can call the function you want otherwise use keymap look up to call the function in the global map.

Advicing
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Around_002dAdvice.html#Around_002dAdvice
Helm Keymap 
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm.el#L101
Keymap lookup
[Given an emacs command name, how would you find key-bindings ? (and vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965263/given-an-emacs-command-name-how-would-you-find-key-bindings-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, find out what major mode is active in the buffer in which you want to change the key binding. You can do that with `C-h v major-mode`, or look in your mode-line.

Then, use `local-set-key` to create the binding for that major mode only by putting some code in the mode hook. I'm not familiar with helm, but let's say the major mode is called `helm-mode`, and it has a hook `helm-mode-hook` and the command you want to bind is called `helm-do-something`:

```
(add-hook 'helm-mode-hook
    (lambda () (local-set-key [tab] 'helm-do-something)))
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I haven't gotten it to work. While `helm-mode` does exist, it does not seem to be invoked automatically in Helm windows.